# Check for the value of a specific attribute in a nested list of objects

Tags: python, azure

I'm working with the Azure SDK - and want to check for the presence of a single RewriteRule as part of a function to return `True` if present or `False` if not

I've created a loop to do it, but wondered if there was a more elegant, and less verbose solution to solve it. At the top level of the loop is a list of rewrite_rule sets

```py
>>> application_gateway.rewrite_rule_sets
[<azure.mgmt.network.v2021_08_01.models._models_py3.ApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleSet object at 0x7f34371f5850>, <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_08_01.models._models_py3.ApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleSet object at 0x7f343614ad00>]
```

I first want to determine whether the name of one of those rule sets is an expected value, and if it is,

I can do that with:

```py
(x for x in application_gateway.rewrite_rule_sets if x.name == 'RequiredRules')
```

Or I could do

```py
for rewrite_rule_sets in application_gateway.rewrite_rule_sets:
    if getattr(rewrite_rule_sets, 'name') == 'Joomla-Rule-Set':
```

Now inside the rewrite_rule_set is a list of rewrite_rules. Each of these rewrite_rules is an object of `ApplicationGatewayRewriteRule` and has a name attribute, among others. I want to check for the name attribute value to be a specific value.

The list of objects is like this

```py
[<azure.mgmt.network.v2021_08_01.models._models_py3.ApplicationGatewayRewriteRule object at 0x7f3436701a30>, <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_08_01.models._models_py3.ApplicationGatewayRewriteRule object at 0x7f3436701880>, <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_08_01.models._models_py3.ApplicationGatewayRewriteRule object at 0x7f34371f5760>, <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_08_01.models._models_py3.ApplicationGatewayRewriteRule object at 0x7f343614ae80>, <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_08_01.models._models_py3.ApplicationGatewayRewriteRule object at 0x7f343614a820>]
```

With each object looking like this

```py
{'additional_properties': {}, 'name': 'GitRemoval', 'rule_sequence': 102, 'conditions': [<azure.mgmt.network.v2021_08_01.models._models_py3.ApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleCondition object at 0x7f3435ef6850>], 'action_set': <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_08_01.models._models_py3.ApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleActionSet object at 0x7f3435ef6790>}
```

My current function looks like this, but feels a little clunky, are there any ways to make this slightly more efficient?

```py
def is_present():
    for rewrite_rule_sets in application_gateway.rewrite_rule_sets:
        if getattr(rewrite_rule_sets, 'name') == 'Joomla-Rule-Set':
            for rewrite_rule in rewrite_rule_sets.rewrite_rules:
                if getattr(rewrite_rule, 'name') == 'MaintenanceRewrite':
                    return True
                else:
                    continue
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

- It is not that efficient to use nested loops. When there are so many objects in your `application_gateway.rewrite_rule_sets` and `rewrite_rule_sets.rewrite_rules` ,the performance gets effected because of the usage of nested loops.
- But, in this case,  `application_gateway.rewrite_rule_sets` is a list of objects (`rewrite_rule_sets`). And each of these objects also contains a list of objects (`rewrite_rules`). So, there might be no way to make this process efficient.
- The code you have written returns `False` only if there is `Joomla-Rule-Set` in the name attribute of `rewrite_rule-sets` object. If `Joomla-Rule-Set` in absent, the first `if` statement returns `False` always and the execution does not proceed further and causes `is_present()` to return `None` which might be an issue. The code given below returns `False` when there is no `MaintenanceRewrite` or `Joomla-Rule-Set`.

```
def is_present(): 
    for rewrite_rule_sets in application_gateway.rewrite_rule_sets: 
        if( getattr(rewrite_rule_sets, 'name') == 'Joomla-Rule-Set' ): 
 
            for rewrite_rule in rewrite_rule_sets.rewrite_rules: 
                if( getattr(rewrite_rule, 'name') == 'MaintenanceRewrite'): 
                    return True 
    return False
```